# Reading the binary file shows unreadable characters

Tags: python

Here is the binary file:

ftp://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SAN/GLAS/GLA14.034/2003.02.28/GLA14_634_1102_002_0071_0_01_0001.DAT

I tried to read that file:

```
fname = "GLA14_634_1102_002_0071_0_01_0001.DAT"
with open (fname, 'rb') as fi:
    lines = fi.read().splitlines()
    print len(lines)    
    print lines[-1]
```

The number of lines '844514' seems correct.

BUT the last line is shown as unreadable characters.

How can I read it correctly?

Comment: What do you expect? Looks like most of the file is non-textual binary data. What do you mean correctly?

Comment: A binary file does not have lines.

Comment: the expected result is readable text/numbers

Comment: @Tichodroma Anyway, how can i convert it into ascii?

Comment: Can you just add a sample of the binary file that includes the intersting bytes? The file is *very* large.

Answer (score 0):

The 'last line' of the shortened example file starts with these bytes:

```
In [49]: lines[-1][:20]
Out[49]: b'\x01\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Converting it to `int`:

```
In [50]: [int(x) for x in lines[-1][:20]]
Out[50]: [1, 168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

On `lines[-1][1]` we have `168` which is outside the range for ASCII.

You will have to find out what encoding is used in this file if you want to convert it to printable charcters.

**Edit:**

If you can use a UNIX-like system, you can use the [`strings`](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) util ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)).

```
$ strings GLA14_634_1102_002_0071_0_01_0001.DAT | head -20
Recl=10000;
Numhead=2;
size_mb_ecs_data_granule=267.57240295410156;
time_between_contiguous_records=1;
instrument_short_name=GLAS;
platform_short_name=Icesat;
sensor_short_name=LaserAlt;
glas_osc_rate.1=1.000000028;
glas_osc_rate_date.1=2003-02-20;
glas_osc_rate_time.1=00:00:00;
sc_osc_rate.1=0.99999998864727;
sc_osc_rate_date.1=2003-02-20;
sc_osc_rate_time.1=00:00:00;
internal_time_delay.1=15.11;
internal_time_delay_date.1=2003-02-20;
internal_time_delay_time.1=00:00:00;
internal_range_delay.1=9556;
internal_range_delay_date.1=2003-02-20;
internal_range_delay_time.1=00:00:00;
ReprocessingPlanned=no further update anticipated;
```

Comment: The document says Data are in scaled integer binary format, big-endian (Unix) byte order. How can I read it then?

Comment: You *can* read them. But you *can't* convert them to ASCII. What do you want to do with them? Why do you need ASCII?

Comment: I want to read the file in order to convert/save as ascii file

Comment: You *can't* convert `168` to ASCII. That's impossible. Please be more spcific about what you want to do. Do you need only the part of the file that *can* be converted to ASCII?

Comment: I want to convert all file contents into other printable format.

Comment: So know please be more specific **what** you want. The ASCII-Data in the header (see my post) or the image data in the binary part, which you cannot convert to ascii, because this are images!

Comment: @Daniel I want the binary part

Comment: @Daniel Can not binary images be converted into other readable format such as TIFF images?

Comment: @cleo: What do you want to do with the data you get out of this files? Then you know in what format you need them. You cannot say, «oh I want some data». You want the data to do something. And my question, and I think the question of many others reading here, is, what this something is.

Comment: @Daniel The DAT file provides laser altimetry data of the global land surface

Comment: @Cleo That is the *meaning* of the content. But what *format* is it? Is it an image, what kind of image, are there any boundaries to identify start and end, are there more than one image, do they have metadata attached? Please find out how such a `.dat` file is structured internally. Then come back.

Comment: @Tichodroma I also do not know and I do not think there are documents that describe all these things in detail. That's why if I can read the contents, I can figure out its structure, and then convert into numpy arrrays for the sections what i need. So my first requiremnt is to to able to read the contents (the binary part)

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to be a mixed text and binary file. The first 20000 bytes are text, then follows some binary data. There seems to be no reference to the start of the binary data in the text-part. So I think the 20000 bytes are fixed.

So you get the text part with this:

```
TEXT_PART_SIZE = 20000

filename = "GLA14_634_1102_002_0071_0_01_0001.DAT"
with open(filename, 'rb') as data:
    text_lines = data.read(TEXT_PART_SIZE).strip().splitlines()
```

The text lines provide some meta-data, perhaps to decode the following binary data. Without a detailed description it is impossible, to read this binary data. It seems, there are 15 Datasets and 200 individual files packed in one big file.
With the help of the `struct`-module and the file format description you can easily read such files.

Comment: i am looking for unpacking the binary parts

Comment: Then you'd better find yourself some documentation on the file format.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams The document says Data are in scaled integer binary format, big-endian (Unix) byte order. How can I read it then?

Comment: On first sight I didn't found a document, that says, there is a mixed text-binary-format. I've only found descriptions of the binary format, which doesn't seem to fit to the file you provided. But I think you have the correct documentation. So read it and do what it says. The `struct`-module is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with GLA14 ICESat data records.  The information you want about the byte structure should also be found at the NSIDC (https://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/glas_altimetry/gla14_records.html).  As for the ascii text header(s), everybody was correct that there is a fixed length.  That length is described by the first two ascii lines (Recl=10000, that is record length, and Numhead=2, that is the number of 10000 byte length records in the header) after you read those 20000 bytes, you will start to read the GLA14 variables.